# Arch Linux как подключиться к wifi

Tags: linux, wifi, archlinux

Не получается подключиться к интернету. Wifi-menu почему то нет.
По другому не знаю как. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Прочитать на вики арча. Но вообще зачем брать арч, если ты в нём ничего не можешь?

Comment: Через телефон по проводу дай инет и установи необходимый софт + на вики арча все прописано.

Comment: `wifi-menu` не так давно вырезали. Пробуйте `iwctl`.